# Is there a method to display dynamic information to the user BEFORE a build?

Tags: jenkins

Within the Jenkins UI, on the project page, you can use the Description Setter plugin to set a description AFTER a build. Is there any way to dynamically set this before a build? I would want to pull information from a file in the workspace that shows information about files that will be changed when the user builds the project.

Edit: While I haven't found a way to dynamically set the project description, I did find that I can create an Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter, give it a descriptive name that serves as a title, and then read the contents of a file containing HTML with a Groovy script like so..

```
// The contents of the file should be HTML
String contents = new File('/tmp/some_file.html').text
return contents
```

So I made this my last parameter, and it shows the information that I need to show, before the end user clicks the build button. Solves my problem.

I'm going to leave this question open though, in case someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't found a way to dynamically set the project description, I did find that I can create an **Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter** (this requires the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)),
Give it a descriptive name that serves as a title, and then read the contents of a file containing HTML with a Groovy script like so..

```
// The contents of the file should be HTML
String contents = new File('/tmp/some_file.html').text
return contents
```

You will need to select a **Choice Type** of: **Formatted HTML**.

So I made this my last parameter, and it shows the information that I need to show, before the end user clicks the build button. Solves my problem.

Comment: One thing to note, for the **Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter**, you will need to select a **Choice Type** of: **Formatted HTML**, in order to display the HTML contents from your file read by the groovy script.